# SSRS drill-down report not filtering on parameters correctly

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008

I have a pair of stored procedures in SQL Server, "Rollup" and "DrillDown".  I want to display them using SSRS.

- "Rollup" will break down the records in four groups (kind, gender, color, emotional_state) and display total records in these categories.  These category-totals will be hyperlinks.  In the sketch below, each `n` is a link.
- "DrillDown", when a link is clicked, will open a new report that lists the records.

  ```
  Rollup:
                        |   emotional_state    | 
  kind   gender   color | happy | sad  | angry | 
  -----|--------|-------|-------|------|-------| 
  cat  | female | brown |   n   |  n   |   n   | 
  cat  | female | white |   n   |  n   |   n   | 
  cat  | female | black |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  cat  |  male  | brown |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  cat  |  male  | white |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  | female | brown |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  | female | white |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  | female | black |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  |  male  | brown |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  |  male  | white |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  dog  |  male  | black |   n   |  n   |   n   |
  ```

The problem is most `n` links don't bring up the correct details.  A few do.  The responses are consistent.  It appears for some links the parameters aren't being passed to the DrillDown procedure.

There's no problem running DrillDown with parameters from SQL Server.  For example, from this `EXEC` call and others like it I get expected results:

```
EXEC my_shema.DrillDown
      @kind             = 'cat',
      @gender           = 'female',
      @color            = 'brown',
      @emotional_state  = 'happy'
```

I am able to replicate the intended report as an Excel pivot table.  To do this, I ran `my_shema.DrillDown` with all `NULL` parameters (obviously the procedure is configured to accept this).  I exported to Excel, inserted a pivot table and got a rendering just like above.  The totals agree with "Rollup" and the click-through takes me to the correct details.

To me that means the problem has to be in one of these places:

- the SSRS design for "Rollup" in Report Builder 3.0.
- the SSRS design for "Drilldown" in Report Builder 3.0.
- settings for one of these reports in the "Manage > Parameters" menu (found in the same browser view that lets you view the report).

Between those three places, there are dozens of points where I can inspect parameters and twiddle with their settings.  But nothing helps.  How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Make the parameters visible on the DrillDown report for testing. When you link to it, are they set correctly based on the link you clicked on? If not, start by looking at the action properties for how it's passing the parameters. Avoid using a URL action if you can, that introduces more issues.

Comment: The parameter values aren't correct.  Action properties for Rollup appear straight forward and correct.  What next?  (And wouldn't you like to make this an Answer, in case of a breakthrough?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to rebuild at least one of the reports.  I rebuilt Rollup and everything works well.

As I said, there are many places to visit to fully understand parameters.  I believe my problem was most likely caused by visiting many of them and worsening the situation by experimenting with fixes.  Starting fresh on the Rollup report looked promising when I realized I'd built in the four parameters when actually it doesn't even use them.  (I had been wondering if a parameter is a kind of object variable which needs a defined scope for visibility to the other object/report.  No...it's not that complicated.)

Plus, I discovered that rebuilding the report only took 15 minutes.  It felt embarrassing after I had spent a few hours kicking at the first version, but I'm new to SSRS so it's just another thing to learn.

@StevenWhite's comment was very helpful, indirectly.  Besides offering a useful initial approach, it got me thinking more clearly in general.